# Oracle SQL: Update a table with difference in value from two other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create an inventory management sort of system for my project and would really appreciate any input anyone has.
I'm trying to update a table (`Current`) with the difference in values from my `Count` and `Used` table.

This is a simplification of what my tables look like.

`Count`

| date | donor | type_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03-JAN-20 | Bob | Rice | 20 |
| 05-JAN-20 | Jan | Pasta | 12 |
| 08-JAN-20 | Bob | Rice | 8 |

`Used`

| date | type_id | used |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03-JAN-20 | Rice | 13 |
| 05-JAN-20 | Pasta | 5 |

I want to update my Current table with this formula.

```
select (a.ct - b.us) as diff
from
(select sum(count) as ct, type_id from NATHANIA.inventory_fact where type_id = 'Rice' group by type_id) a
left join
(
select sum(used) as us, type_id from NATHANIA.inventory_used where type_id = 'Rice' group by type_id) b
on a.type_id = b.type_id;
```

The output gives me 15 (20+8-13). I'm having trouble updating my `Current` table accordingly.

`Current`

| type_id | current_count |
| --- | --- |
| Rice | 15 |
| Pasta | 2 |

I tried using a cte but it's giving me this error: "UPDATE ... SET expression must be a subquery".

```
update NATHANIA.inventory_current t1
    set (t1.type, t1.current_count) = (
        with cte1 as ( 
            select a.ct-b.us as diff
            from
            (select sum(count) as ct, type_id from NATHANIA.inventory_fact where type_id = 'Rice' group by type_id) a
            left join
            (select sum(used) as us, type_id from NATHANIA.inventory_used where type_id = 'Rice' group by type_id) b
            on a.type_id = b.type_id
        )
    select type_id, diff from cte1 where t1.type = cte1.type_id
    );
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any information, this is my first stack question :)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the MERGE statement for cases like this - you have your query results with a key field and whatever the new data needs to be. MERGE is a very straightforward way to wrap that query and insert/update/delete as needed.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9017.htm#SQLRF01606

example code might look like the following - haven't tested, but the link above provides all necessary syntax details:

```
MERGE INTO NATHANIA.inventory_current t1
    USING (
        select a.type_id,
        (a.ct - b.us) as diff
        from
        (select sum(count) as ct, type_id from NATHANIA.inventory_fact where type_id = 'Rice' group by type_id) a
        left join
        (
        select sum(used) as us, type_id from NATHANIA.inventory_used where type_id = 'Rice' group by type_id) b
        on a.type_id = b.type_id
    ) s
ON ( t1.type = s.type_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
set t1.current_count = s.diff
```